# jQuery slideshow not working, display:none;

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get my jquery slideshow working only for some reason its outputting to the browser as display:none!

Theres quite a bit of code so ive made a fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/uExdD/

Can anbybody see where im going wrong? Im using this plugin

http://basic-slider.com/

I call my plugin with the following...

```
 $('.slideshow').bjqs({
      'animation' : 'slide',
      'width' : 960,
      'height' : 335,
      'showMarkers': true
    });
```

Comment: You have an error in your JS...

Comment: By the output from my browser I could see it's related to your $m_markers variable behaviour. Double check it for errors. Sorry for not being able to help more

Comment: If you get the inital bit right (see below) you wont get the error that Bruno mentioned.

Comment: As @gapple suggested ... the plugin is expecting an ul of with class bjqs ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong...

```
$slider         = $wrapper.find('ul.bjqs'),
```

Or rather, your markup should be...

```
<section class="slideshow">
        <ul class="bjqs">
```

You can either change the class in the markup or use your custom class in the script instead of .bjqs

Answer (score 4):

As specified in the documentation, your `<ul>` tag needs a `bjqs` class.

```
<section class="slideshow">
  <ul class="bjqs home-slideshow">
    <!-- ... -->
  </ul>
</section>
```